# пересылка данных во Fragment

Tags: java, android

Код данной активити получает ответ от сервера и по задумке должен отправить результат во фрагмент.

```
public void Okhhtp(){


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(link)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new

        Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure (Call call, IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse (Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
              final String result = response.body().string();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("a", result);
                        dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });

            }

        });


    }
```

ответ от сервера пришел, об этом говорит "тост" содержащий ответ сервера, фрагмент открылся, об этом говорит текст вью отображающееся на экране,  но 
содержимое ответа не передается во фрагмент.. в текст вью.

код Fragment

```
public class DialogFragment extends Fragment {
        String b;
    TextView text;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);

        text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);






        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            b = bundle.getString("a");
            text.setText(b);


        }

        return view;
    }
```

Кусок кода открытия фрагмента

```
if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentClass = DialogFragment.class;
            try {
                Okhhtp();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

весь код главного активити

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment dialogFragment = new com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment();
    public String a = "gfgf";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    ArrayList<Sdialog> UpList = new ArrayList<>();
  Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
ProfilFragment profilFragment = new ProfilFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        //fragmentManager.beginTransaction()          // получаем экземпляр FragmentTransaction
                //.replace(R.id.container, dialogFragment).commit();            // вызываем commit для совершения действий FragmentTransaction


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //bundle = new Bundle();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass = null;

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragmentClass = com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment.class;
            try {
                Okhhtp();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragmentClass = ProfilFragment.class;
            try {
                Okhhtp();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragmentClass = DialogFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            fragmentClass = DialogFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            fragmentClass = DialogFragment.class;
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            fragmentClass = DialogFragment.class;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
        item.setChecked(true);
        // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
        setTitle(item.getTitle());

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


  public void Okhhtp(){


        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://123.party/")
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new

        Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure (Call call, IOException e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse (Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
              final String result = response.body().string();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                       // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                       // bundle.putString("a", result);
                        //dialogFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        dialogFragment.setResult(result);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });

            }

        });


    }


}
```

Что я делаю не правильно ?

Comment: А где и в какой момент вы открываете фрагмент? Добавьте код.

Comment: У меня большой код вытягивающегося меню с условиями, при нажатии на пункт выполняется условие, я добавил его в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том, что ответ от сервера вы получаете асинхронно. То есть, в момент когда вызывается `onResponse` у коллбека, метод фрагмента `onCreateView` уже отработал с null аргументами.

Сделайте отдельный метод во фрагменте, в который будете передавать результат и устанавливать его в `TextView`:

```
public void setResult(String result) {
    text.setText(result);
}
```

И вызывайте его вместо `setArguments()`:

```
...
@Override
public void onResponse (Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    final String result = response.body().string();
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialogFragment.setResult(result);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
...
```

Таким образом у вас сначала откроется фрагмент, а после получения ответа от сервера заполнится `TextView`.

Проблема с `NullPointerException` возникает из за того, что вы инициализируете `com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment dialogFragment = new com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment();` вначале и ничего с ним не делаете. А потом пытаетесь обратиться к нему. Так как он не добавлен во фрагмент менеджер, у него не отработали методы ЖЦ и TextView не проинициализировался. Исправьте так:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance();
        dialogFragment = fragment;
        try {
            Okhhtp();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
...
    // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
...
}
```

Comment: Java.lang.NullPointerException: попытка вызвать виртуальный метод 'void android.widget.TextView.setText (java.lang.CharSequence)' в ссылке на нулевой объект

Comment: Где вы открываете фрагмент? В кода в вопросе нет этого.

Comment: У меня есть главный активити в нем контейнер в который помещаются фрагменты

Comment: Ну покажите код

Comment: Обновил код вопроса

Comment: `com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment dialogFragment = new com.witryna.Fragment.DialogFragment();` вы объявляете вначале и ничего с ним не делаете. А потом пытаетесь обратиться к нему. Так как он не добавлен во фрагмент менеджер, у него не отработали методы ЖЦ и TextView не проинициализировался.

Comment: я так понимаю перед onCreate я должен написать   DialogFragment dialogFragment;  а перед фрагмент менеджером dialogFragment =  new DialogFragment() ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64566/discussion-between-stt-and-eugeneek).

Comment: Дополнил ответ.